# Java array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, nullpointerexception

I created a class Car. It includes a location, a double array size 2. I'm trying to create an array of Cars. Here is what I have:

```
Car[] cars;
cars = new Car[3];

cars[0].location = new double[]{1,6};
cars[1].location = new double[]{10,30};
cars[2].location = new double[]{20,7};
```

I get an error where I try to declare the location: `NullPointerException`. How do I resolve this?

Comment: You haven't initialized the elements in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create reference variables for the objects in the array.  Your original code simply initializes a Cars array of size 3, but doesn't put any objects inside.

```
Car[] cars;
cars = new Cars[3];

for (int i=0; i<3; i+=1) {
    cars[i] = new Car();
}

cars[0].location = new double[]{1,6};
cars[1].location = new double[]{10,30};    
cars[2].location = new double[]{20,7};
```